# Como fazer os arrays irem de um em um valor?

Tags: javascript

estou tentando fazer que o título do site aqui, sempre mude seu título de tempo em tempo porém eu não sei como fazer isso. ignore o alert ele é só pra eu ver como fica

````
var titulo = [algum, valor, em, algum, lugar]

for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    arraytitu[i] = setInterval(function () {
        if (i < 3) {
            alert(arraytitu);
            i++;
        } else {
            clearInterval(tmp[i])
        }
    }, 1000);
}```
````

Comment: no caso, eu não consigo fazer ir cada valor no array, sempre vai todos de uma vez

Answer (score 2):

Não precisa de laço `for`. Só com `setInterval` você já consegue. Basta ir percorrendo cada índice da array até o fim. Quando o valor da variável `indice` for igual ao tamanho da array, cancele o temporizador:

```js
var titulo = ['tit1', 'tit2', 'tit3', 'tit4', 'tit5'];
var indice = 0;
var intervalo = setInterval(function () {
   if (indice < titulo.length) {
      console.log(titulo[indice]);
   } else {
      clearInterval(intervalo);
      console.log("Acabou!");
   }
   indice++;
}, 1000);
```

### Edit

Se quiser um loop infinito na array, pode fazer desta forma:

```js
var titulo = ['tit1', 'tit2', 'tit3', 'tit4', 'tit5'];
var indice = 0;
var intervalo = setInterval(function () {
   console.log(titulo[indice]);
   indice++;
   if (indice == titulo.length) indice = 0;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Ou, para dar a volta: `console.log(titulo[indice % titulo.length]);` (cortando o if/else).

Comment: Lembrando que dependendo do intervalo e de quanto tempo o usuário deixar a página aberta, `indice` vai estourar o limite máximo dos inteiros. Tem diversas maneiras de resolver (inclusive evitando usar a operação de resto, rs), fica como exercício pra quem resolver usar :)